# Where can I find a searchable list of BASIC syntax?

Tags: basic

I am looking for a reference I can use to look up syntax for BASIC. The code is used on an old HP-85, which may affect the command list. I've had issues using Google because every time I search for something like "<> basic command" it thinks I literally mean basic and returns a bunch of introductory tutorials for other languages. I'll also accept an explanation for <> as an answer, below is the line which uses this.

`IF X <> 700 THEN 5462`. How does this decide whether or not to go to line 5462?

Comment: BASIC isn't often used these days, so it is a bit difficult to find reference material - different diallects of BASIC will each have a name, so maybe search for a specific diallect? For example here is a reference for [QB64](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/Keyword_Reference_-_Alphabetical#A)

Comment: And [here](http://www.qb64.net/wiki/index.php/Not_Equal) is the page relating to `<>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<>` means "not equal to" in BASIC and is analogous to the `!=` *operator* in most other languages. To answer your example, this would only go to line 5462 if the variable `X` was anything other than 700 (ie it would always goto 5462 unless X was equal to 700).

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept this answer in a few minutes when I'm able to.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.series80.org/Manuals/ is where your manuals are. I searched **HP-85** and **basic**. For an overview of your computer see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_series_80.